# Allow user to access only his/her dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I have four different layouts.

- HomeLayout - Homepage
- AdminLayout
- UserLayout
- AgentLayout

AdminLayout is the parent for admin related pages and UserLayout for user 
related and so on. I have used Higher Order Component for checking if the 
user is unauthenticated, redirect them to homepage. There is another condition too. That is if the user is authenticated but if the role of user is not admin and the user tries to access AdminDashboard, he/she should be redirected to the Home page and similiarly same with others. But Agent can access UserDashboard.

The role I get is in the form

```
user_role = ['superadmin'] or ['enduser'] or ['agent'] or 
['enduser', 'agent'].
```

One should not access other dashboard except agent can access agent dashboard and user dashboard too. For unauthenticated user I could redirect to homepage when accessing dashboard without loggin in

The code for redirecting to unauthenticated user is working and i have done the following way

```
const Redirection = prop => WrappedComponent => {
  return class Redirection extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      const user_instance = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      if (!user_instance) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      } else {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
  };
};

export default props => WrappedComponent =>
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Redirection(props)(WrappedComponent));
```

AdminLayout

```
class AdminLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Redirection()(AdminLayout);
```

The user_role I get from localStorage is as `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))['userInfo]['user_role']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using lodash `intersection`. Here is the link for it

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection

In your case, the check will be following

```
if (
        user_instance &&
        intersection(prop, user_instance["userInfo"]["user_role"])
          .length > 0
      ) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      }
```

you can glue the following snippet.Also don't forgot to check lodash documentation as it can be very helpful for you down the line